# Не отображаются компоненты и эндпоинты в swagger-ui на Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, swaggerui

Добавил зависимость в пом:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Сконфигурировал:

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {


    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("Тестовое API")
                );
    }

}
```

Создал контроллер:

```java
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public void hello() {

    }
}
```

Итог:

Сваггер не видит контроллера

[image: Пустой сваггер]

Comment: А достучаться до метода контроллера через, к примеру, Postman получается?

Comment: @kami Да, до контроллера достукивает

Comment: а если убрать бин из конфига вообще? Судя по весьма свежему https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation - он не требуется.